# How to properly use SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

How do I use a CASE statement to apply to all values corresponding to a specific field in a column?

For example, I want all payments in every column to appear as negatives but this only applies to the first column.  Also, I want it to apply to all payments in every column.

```
 CASE WHEN ardoc.DocType = 'PA' 
      THEN arDoc.DocBal*(-1) ELSE ardoc.DocBal 
 END AS [Document Balance]
```

Note:  'PA' stands for payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid repeating the expression in this case with something like

```
SELECT DocBal = multiplier * DocBal,
       Col2 = multiplier * Col2,
       Col3 = multiplier * Col3
FROM   arDoc
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(IIF(DocType = 'PA', -1, 1))) V(multiplier);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Martin

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write a single CASE expression that will return more than one column.  You will need to write a separate CASE for each column.

Answer (score 0):

As Tab Allerman said, you can't do this with a single CASE statement but there might be another approach.

Create a table (temporary or permanent) that contains the DocType plus a multiplier, then join to this.

Something like

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(DocType varchar(2), multiplier int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('PA', -1),
('XX', 1),
('YY', 1)
```

Then you query would look something like

```
SELECT 
    arDoc.DocBal * ISNULL(t.Multiplier, 1) as [Document Balance],
    myNextColumn * ISNULL(t.Multiplier, 1) as [My Next Output Column]
From MyTable a
    LEFT JOIN @t t on a.DocType = t.DocType
```

I've done a left join here and used ISNULL so that if no entry is found in @t then it assumes a multiplier of 1.

You still have to do each column but the code smaller and if you need new multipliers, you don't have to change the case statements.